# Problem in Eloqua campaign when using Eloqua app connector with Bulk API

Tags: eloqua

I have used Eloqua app connector in campaign. Its good to execute max 5000 records , that's Record per notification set to 5000, but I want export records more than 5000, so I update Record per notification is Zero as per the [Eloqua documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/Developers/BulkAPI/Tutorials/retrieving_records.htm) and then export using Bulk API.
I have success fully received all contacts Ex: 10074 contacts I have exported from eloqua each 1000 vice versa and saved in to Azure container

Only one issue I faced, thats in campaign, contacts not shown on wait step, still showing on App connector, contact status is fine as Awaiting action for each contacts. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app is performing the export, the app needs to update the record status using a Bulk API [sync action](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/Developers/BulkAPI/Reference/Syncs/sync-actions.htm). See the AppCloud responses.

Typically, the app provider will add a sync action to the export definition of the records in the step to set them to "active" upon export. The app provider could also set them to "complete" upon export, which would move them to the next step upon successful export, but it is common to have an action that should be completed before moving the records to the next step.

Using an Action Service as an example, the app will then perform action, then use a sync action to set the record's status after result of action, i.e. "complete" for success or "error" for failure. If data needs to be updated in Eloqua the sync action can be added to the import definition, this would be for the happy success path. If data does not need to be updated after action, a [sync action definition](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/op-api-bulk-2.0-contacts-syncactions-post.html) can be used to just update the record status without importing any data. A separate sync action definition would be needed if there are any records that need to be set to error.